# Rate limiting / scheduling AWS Cognito operations to avoid TooManyRequestsException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, job-scheduling, rate-limiting

AWS Cognito UserUpdate related operations have a quota of 25 requests per second (a hard limit which can't be increased)

I have a Lambda function which gets 1000 simultaneous requests and is responsible for calling Cognito's AdminUpdateUserAttributes operation. as a result, some requests pass and some fails do to `TooManyRequestsException`.

Important to note that these 1000 requests happens on a daily basis, one time on each day in the morning. there are no requests at all during the entire day.

Our stack is completely serverless and managed by cloudformation (with serverless framework) and we tend to avoid using EC2 if possible.

What is the best way to handle these daily 1000 requests so that they will be handled as soon a I get them, while avoiding failures due to `TooManyRequestsException`

A solution I tried:
A lambda that receives the requests and sends them to an SQS + another lambda with reserved concurrency of 1 that is triggered from events in the SQS which calls Congito's AdminUpdateUserAttributes operation.

This solution partially worked as I didn't get `TooManyRequestsException` exceptions anymore but looks like some of the messages got lost in the way (I think that is because SQS got throttled).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AWS recommends [exponential backoff with jitter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/exponential-backoff-and-jitter/) for any API operations that are rate-limited or produce retryable failures.

Answer (score 0):

Standard queues support a nearly unlimited number of API calls per second, per API action (SendMessage, ReceiveMessage, or DeleteMessage).

are you sure the SQS got throttled?

another option to increase failed lambda retires.